# Python, Django: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.Usuarios' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

Good morning! Although questions similar to this have been posted here, I have not been able to resolve my issue yet. I have tried all proposed solutions.

The problem started after I put, or at least tried to put, "email" as the username, removing the username from the model.

I will share the points that I think are relevant. If you need more, you can ask.

problem:

```
PS C:\SocialFacil\socialfacil_web> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 235, in get_model
    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'usuarios'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 170, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 213, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 237, in get_model
    raise LookupError(
LookupError: App 'accounts' doesn't have a 'Usuarios' model.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\SocialFacil\socialfacil_web\accounts\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 18, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "C:\SocialFacil\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 176, in get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.Usuarios' that has not been installed
PS C:\SocialFacil\socialfacil_web>
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'core',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Usuarios'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'accounts.authemail.EmailBackend',
]
```

accounts/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils import timezone


class UsuariosManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('O Email é obrigatório')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class Usuarios(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    objects = UsuariosManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        # Remova o campo de username dos campos renderizados automaticamente
        if UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:
            del self.fields[UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD]
```

accounts/authemail.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
```

I'm hoping for a solution to the problem that I've been trying to solve for over 20 hours :D

Comment: Make sure there is an empty __init__.py file in your accounts app. Also, does it work fine if you remove the line `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`?